# How to place Image EXACTLY where I want (and responsive) within Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, navbar

I need to mimic the navbar in www.nielsen.com, currently my Image isn't at the top of the Navbar and I need it to be aligned with the left of the title and move depending on screen size. How do I do this?

```css
/* Navigation */
#menu.navbar-default {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0);
 height: 65px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.nielsen.com/us/en.html"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKSTL.png" width="45" height="65" alt="Nielsen"> </a> </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your image, understand and add the following CSS:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

For your background image, understand and add the following CSS:

```
background: url(...) center;
background-size: 1000px;
```

Comment: Beyond this, I would need to see your problem, either with a link to your website or a demo of your problem on JSfiddle, CodePen, or a more detailed snippet.

Comment: This doesnt do anything apart from put the image in the middle of my nav bar, its still not at the top.

Comment: @OllieRichardson For a CodePen, add your `<script src="...">` and `<link href="">` to the top of the html.